# Full lyrics of favorite camp song (called "Gypsy Song") containing "… faria faria-O"

Tags: lyrics

I’m looking for the English lyrics to a song I learned at summer camp. It was called "Gypsy Song".

The refrain was

> Set the forest and mountains ringing with faria faria-O

Comment: This link : https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cambridge-woodcraft.org.uk%2Fresources%2FPioneer%2520songs%2520with%2520guitar%2520chords.pdf&ei=6FQJVf6BIqOI7QbDjoDgDA&usg=AFQjCNF1SQIUV3LR-rysLqxyjDGVbJT1zA&sig2=PXFy2yXDNQ99C8LoUKqCkQ&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s might have lyrics - unfortunately I can't open it on my machine to check :(

Comment: Presumably you're not thinking of just "Faria" (aka "Gypsy Life")? E.g. see http://mudcat.org/detail_pf.cfm?messages__Message_ID=282852.

Comment: They're very similar to it but they aren't the same song.:(

Comment: Since nobody has come up with an answer it looks very much as if "Gypsy Life" and "Gypsy Song" are two different English interpretations of a very well known old German song. Since the OP, who hasn't been here since 2015, is the only person in a position to judge the correctness of a possible answer, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is all I can remember. I've been looking too.

> Laugh and leave all your cares behind you
>   faria faria o
>   Never worry where night will find you
>   faria faria o
>   what if all your money's gone
>   When you've nothing to spend it on
>   Set the forest and mountains ringing with
>   faria faria o

Answer (score 1):

There is a German traditional song with the same refrain, but I have no idea, whether the melody is also the same.

Sources date the song back to first half of 19th century.

The text can be found here
[Songtexte.com](https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/freddy-quinn/lustig-ist-das-zigeunerleben-63cdb627.html), a video on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/U2nBU6qlyj4).

Answer (score 1):

Lustig ist das Zigeunerleben, faria faria ho
Brauche dem Kaiser kein Steuer zu geben, faria faria, ho
Lustig ist es im tiefen Wald,
wo der Zigeuner Aufenenthalt,
faria, faria, faria, faria, faria, faria ho.

1.Strophe von "Lustig ist das Zigeunerleben"

Comment: While this is almost certainly the original version of the song, the original poster is looking for the English lyrics.